# How to setup Salesforce.com as an Identity Provider for sharepoint application

Tags: sharepoint-2010, amazon-web-services, salesforce, identity

I am looking for a solution/implementation steps for integrating Salesforce.com Identity Provider for share point team site application. We have a salesforce org and also share point 2010 application is running in AWS ec2 server. I would like to authenticate my share point team site from salesforce.com login.

it would be very much appreciable, if any one share your ideas/solution.